# Prove $a_t \leq \frac{c}{t}$

Tags: optimization, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

We have the recursive equation $$a_t^2 = (1 - a_t)a_{t-1}^2$$ $$a_0 = 1$$

Prove that there exists constant $c$ such that $a_t \leq \frac{c}{t}$, and find the smallest such $c$.

I was able to get that $a_t^2 = (1 - a_t)(1 - a_{t-1})\dots(1 - a_1)$, but I don't know how to proceed after that, and I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: If
$a_t^2 = (1 - a_t)a_{t-1}^2
$
and
$a_0 = 0$
then it looks like
all $a_t = 0$.

Comment: @martycohen You're right. My mistake, it should be $a_0 = 1$. Edited the post.

Comment: That's better. Also, $a$ is much easier to type than \theta.

Comment: Good point. I think I'll edit that in as well.

Comment: Is the sequence well defined past $t=1$? $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, and $a_2$ must satisfy the quadratic $x^2 + x/4 - 1/4$ which has strictly positive discriminant hence two solutions.

Comment: @Neal This is also a question I had. First, we impose the condition $a_t$ > 0. I'm not sure this will be enough, but my understanding is that the bound should apply regardless of which value of $a_t$ you select. Also, I believe $a_1$ is $\frac{-1 + \sqrt5}{2}$?

Comment: If you want the sequence to be positive, you must always use the positive equare root. That's what I did in my answer.

Comment: @sedrick That makes sense, and I think you're right about $a_1$, I messed that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turn out that
$c \ge 2$ will work.

$a_t^2 
= (1 - a_t)a_{t-1}^2
$.

$a_1^2
= 1-a_1$
so
$a_1
=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}
=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$.

$a_t^2+a_ta_{t-1}^2-a_{t-1}^2
= 0
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
a_t
&=\dfrac{-a_{t-1}^2+\sqrt{a_{t-1}^4+4a_{t-1}^2}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{-a_{t-1}^2+a_{t-1}\sqrt{a_{t-1}^2+4}}{2}\\
&=a_{t-1}\dfrac{-a_{t-1}+\sqrt{a_{t-1}^2+4}}{2}\\
&=a_{t-1}\dfrac{-a_{t-1}+\sqrt{a_{t-1}^2+4}}{2}\dfrac{a_{t-1}+\sqrt{a_{t-1}^2+4}}{a_{t-1}+\sqrt{a_{t-1}^2+4}}\\
&=a_{t-1}\dfrac{2}{a_{t-1}+\sqrt{a_{t-1}^2+4}}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+4/a_{t-1}^2}}\\
\text{if}
&a_{t-1} \le \dfrac{c}{t-1}\\
a_t
&\le\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+4/(c/(t-1))^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+4(t-1)^2/c^2}}\\
&\lt\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{4(t-1)^2/c^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{1+2(t-1)/c}\\
\end{array}
$

so we want
$\dfrac{2}{1+2(t-1)/c}
\le \dfrac{c}{t}
$
or
$\dfrac{2c}{c+2(t-1)}
\le \dfrac{c}{t}
$
or
$2t
\le c+2(t-1)
=2t+c-2
$
or
$c \ge 2$.

Therefore
$c \ge 2$
will work.

Comment: This solution is very clean. Thanks! Just a question, so is $2$, the minimum as well? Or is $2$ just one such value that works?

Comment: Any $c \ge 2$ will work because if $a_t \le 2/t$ then $a_t \le c/t$ for $c > 2$.

Comment: @sedrick I don't think a lower value of $c$ can be found, since it is easy to show that the procedure followed above is optimal.